# Javascript is not showing desired Values

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, custom-fields

I am trying to manipulate gravity forms with the Custom fields to show the stores(along with assigning email to hidden field) in my form based on the state using the JSON and JavaScript.Same code is working for other website, but not yielding any result when i select state in the form. Please help me in navigating this issue.

I tried searching for similar answer but i didn't have any luck(also I am new so I am not very familiar with JSON).

Let me know if my way of posting question is right or there any edits need to be done?

PHP CODE:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_state_list_book_appointment','state_list_book_appointment');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_state_list_book_appointment','state_list_book_appointment');
function state_list_book_appointment()
{

    $states = get_field('state_options', 'option');

    $output = [];
    foreach ($states as $state) {
        if ($state['booking_Appointment']) {
             $output[] = [
            'state_name' => $state['store'] . ' (' . $state['state'] . ')',
            'state_email' => $state['store_email']
        ];
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
    die();
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#input_1_4').length > 0) {

        var store_lists_book_appointment;
        $('#input_1_4').on('change', function () {
                current_state = $(this).val();
                output = '';

                state_string = '(' + current_state + ')';
                console.log(state_string);
                $("#input_1_6").val($("#input_1_6 option:first").val());
                $.each($('#input_1_6 option'), function (idx, val) {
                    // assume state is in option format of ([state])
                    idx_of_state = $(val).val().indexOf(state_string);
                    if (idx == 0 || idx_of_state > 0) {
                        $(val).show();
                    } else {
                        $(val).hide();
                    }
                });
            });

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: my_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data:{action: 'state_list_book_appointment'},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#catvalue').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-1x" style="color:#000;text-align:center;"></i>');
            },
                    dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.log (data);
                    store_lists = JSON.parse(data);
                    //console.log(store_lists);
                    //store_lists_women = JSON.parse(data).women;
                    output = '<option>-- Please select --</option>';
                    $.each(store_lists, function (index, value) {
                        output += '<option style="display:none" value="' + value.state_name + '" data-email="' + value.state_email + '">' + value.state_name + '</option>';
                    });
                    $('#input_1_6').html(output);

                }
            });




            $('#input_1_6').on('change', function () {
                selected_email = $('#input_1_6 option:selected').data('email');
                $('#input_1_10').val(selected_email);
            });


        // This function is to prevent Chrome frontend validation. It stop working actual submit function of the form
        $('#gform_submit_button_1').on('click', function(){
            $('#gform_1').submit();
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the console?

Comment: try changing '$('#input_1_6').on('change', function ()' to '$(document).on('change','#input_1_6',function(e) {...}', and then the same for all your onchange events. It's just a guess without knowing any errors.

Comment: I was getting an error Message earlier: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data but i changed the datatype:'json' and now there is no error message.

Comment: It's a bit unusal to see 'get' as the post type. Should normaly be 'post'

Comment: I did the change you asked but it is still not working. Am i missing any element apart from php and javascript?

Comment: No I don't think so. It could be anything like a simple typo. Perhaps put a console.log in the $('#input_1_6').on('change', function () to confirm that selectred_email is getting assigned a value, i.e that the onchange event is firing.

Comment: I am able to select the state i.e on change of '#input_1_4') , the javascript is sending value to console log but its not showing stores for option of 1_6 for selected value.(Both are dropdown)

Comment: Add and "error: function(errorThrown) {...}" check to the ajax function, so you can see if the ajax is throwing an error.

Comment: ok, having a look...

Comment: debugging show 'store_lists' as undefined, Please change "store_lists = JSON.parse(data);" to "var store_lists = JSON.parse(data);". Looking again I see many variables don;t have 'var', so I am not sure about that.

Comment: Your ajax function only fires on load, not on any event. That I am 100% sure of. I think perhaps you have close off the  $('#input_1_4').on('change', function () { too early (with "})", which should maybe go after the ajax function.. It is after all the ajax function that should update the options when selecting the state?

Comment: Hi Gavin, thank you for looking at the question but I found the error. As I was using child theme to customize the data, i was declaring ajax variable again to fetch in URL while the main theme already had ajax enabled, i think that was conflicting with the js and was not sending any calls.I changed the Url variable call element to default theme and it started working. So Now its working.The code was otherwise okay.

Comment: Good to hear, well done.